# Heroku redis remote connection

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have had the redis instance working for some time but now i'm trying to connect to my Redis addon and i'm getting a timeout error while connecting.
My app is made with nodejs, using redis module and i have already tried with process.env.REDIS_URL and with the full url and it's not connecting

Anyone knows if Heroku addons allow remote connection? even with redis -h URL is not working

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, you have to parse the REDIS_URL into different parts to use the creds on your redis client. Username has no use in redis, only password URL and port are important.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i've done it too and still it time's out

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall problem that shuts down this port? Can you try accessing to the redis through a vps on amazon / any provider so you can check you don't have network rules that prevent you to access the remote redis?

Comment: In my pc i can't access i get timeout accesing via CLI so idk if it may be blocking from here.

Comment: But the strange part is, on the app it shouldn't be blocking because its hosted on the amazon services from heroku and so does the redis of heroku. My firewall would never interefere

Comment: Which library do you use to get access to redis? IORedis? Or another library? Did you check that the redis url did not rotate (as it often does) and you can no longer use the URL you are testing?

Comment: I'm using redis not ioREDIS and i have tried already set the property url, crendetials 1 by 1 and also the first param redis url.

Comment: I have my docker redis server working just fine with the url with the same style